# Webpack stuck. How to get more info why?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I've got a project that's an upgraded version of an older electrode project, with some upgrades to webpack 4, babel runtime, etc.

`npm run build` works fine. (It does this: `rimraf lib doc && clap build && bundlesize`)

But `clap dev` is getting stuck here:

```
...
<s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting stats-writer-plugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting unnamed compat plugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting unnamed compat plugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting inspectpack-duplicates-plugin
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting unnamed compat plugin
Total precache size is about 4.77 MB for 22 resources.
```

Not sure if it's an issue with xclap or webpack.

xclap.js:

```
process.env.SERVER_ES6 = true;
process.env.ENABLE_BABEL_POLYFILL = false;
require("electrode-archetype-react-app")();

const xclap = require("xclap");
const Fs = require("fs");
const Path = require("path");
function setDevelopmentEnv() {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = "qa";
}

xclap.load("abc", {
  "fix-generator-eslint": {
    task: () => {
      const pkg = require("./package.json");
      if (pkg.scripts.install === "clap fix-generator-eslint") {
        pkg.scripts.install = "echo OK";
        Fs.writeFileSync(Path.resolve("package.json"), JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2));
        return "~$eslint --fix config src test --ext .js,.jsx";
      }
    }
  }
});

xclap.load("electrode",{
  ".development-env": () => setDevelopmentEnv()
})
```

Any advice on how to debug further? I tried to look into how to get some more verbose output out of webpack, to understand where it's stuck.

I added the verbose options to my webpack config, it doesn't give useful info for the last line.

webpack config:

```
const Path = require("path");
const sassConfig = module.exports = require("./scss.webpack.config.js");

let originalModuleExports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "ele-app-abc": "ele-app-abc/src",
    },
  modules: [
      Path.join("ele-app-abc", "ele-app-abc/node_modules"),
    ]
  },
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/server/index.js",
  stats: {
    assets: true,
    colors: true,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    hash: true,
    verbose: true,
    display: "verbose"
  }
};

module.exports = Object.assign(sassConfig, originalModuleExports);
```

Any pointers?